# how to ask if a variable is equal to a list of words

Tags: r

I am trying to do an ifelse statement that tests if a variable is equal to a series of character strings. In dummy data, I am trying the following:

```
mtcars$mpg <- as.character(mtcars$mpg)
table(ifelse(mtcars$mpg == c("21", "18.1", "14.3"), "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```

I want this to produce 4 Trues, and 28 Falses.

Comment: `table(mtcars$mpg %in% c("21", "18.1", "14.3"))` see `?match`

Comment: Use %in%: 
`table(ifelse(mtcars$mpg %in% c("21", "18.1", "14.3"), "TRUE", "FALSE"))`

Comment: To make clear why the two statements above are correct, when you use `==` on a vector ist looks through `mtcars$mpg` for that full vector NOT the individual values. Using %in% it searches to see if any given value is IN the vector, then it assigns the boolean. 

But I would try `table(ifelse(mtcars$mpg %in% c("21", "18.1", "14.3"), TRUE, FALSE))` because the "" make the strings not true R boolean values